# Horner's Polynomial Evaluation for a postive and negative x

Tags: polynomials, computational-complexity

Solving a polynomial with value $x$ using Horner's method seems to use the least amount of multiplications and additions, 1 of each per pass.  How would you use this with $\pm x$ using only $n + 1$ multiplications and additions?

So $7x^5-3x^3 + 2x^2 +x -5$ would give $13$ multiplications and $4$ additions, total of `17` operations.

With Horner's it would be $(((((7x + 0)x - 3)x + 2)x + 1)x - 5)$ would give $5$ multiplications and additions for a total of 10 operations.

Just using Horner's twice, once for $x$ and once for $-x$ would give you $2n$ multiplications and additions.  I know you could cut down the number of operations because the even powers give the same answers whether a negative or positive is in it. But that isn't near enough.  Is there a relation to the final answers?  I can't find any other similarities when writing out each.

I have looked almost everywhere to find a start, so if someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Split your polynomial into odd and even parts.

The *even* part is $$f_E(x) = a_0 + a_2x^2 + a_4x^4 + \cdots$$
which you can consider a polynomial in $x^2$ and evaluate by $n/2$ steps of Horner's method.

The *odd* part is
$$ f_O(x) = a_1x + a_3x^3+a_5x^5 + \cdots = x(a_1+a_3x^2 + a_5x^4+\cdots) $$
where the bracket on the right is again a polynomial in $x^2$ that you can evaluate in $n/2$ steps. Thereafter it takes only a single multiplication to multiply by $x$.

Now $f(x)=f_E(x)+f_O(x)$ and $f(-x)=f_E(x)-f_O(x)$.

The total additional work compared to evaluating just $f(x)$ directly is one multiplication to create $x^2$, one multiplication to get the single $x$ factor in $f_O$, and one addition and subtraction to combine everything at the end -- no matter what the degree.

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, but not quite it.  Because you still have polynomials of size n.  Since Horner's method needs zero coefficients in place where there isn't that power.  For the even one you would still be solving for $$f_E(x) = a_0 + 0x + a_2x^2 + 0x^3 + a_4x^4 + \cdots$$ and similar for the odd powers.

Comment: @C-Pfef: No, when evaluating $f_E(x)$, you do $$f_E(x) = a_0 + a_2y + a_4y^2 + \cdots $$ where you have computed $y=x^2$ once and for all to begin with.